# Javascript if having AND for two comparisons returns true even if other comparison is false

Tags: javascript

This is copy-paste from Firebug Watch window:

> mMapDevices[i].IsHighlighted *true*
>   mMapDevices[i].Device.NodeTypeCode *"M"*
>   mMapDevices[i].Device.NodeTypeCode !== "M" *false*
>   mMapDevices[i].NodeTypeCode !== "M" && mMapDevices[i].IsHighlighted **true**
>       true && false *false*
>       typeof(mMapDevices[i].Device.NodeTypeCode) *"string"*
>       typeof("M") *"string"*

When running the script the execution goes inside if clause:

```
if (mMapDevices[i].IsHighlighted && mMapDevices[i].NodeTypeCode !== "M") {
```

What is happening here?

Comment: should it not be `mMapDevices[i].Device.NodeTypeCode`?  What you have is probably `undefined`, and would explain the behaviour

Comment: You're correct James. I'm not going crazy, just blind :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is your problem:

`mMapDevices[i].NodeTypeCode !== "M" && mMapDevices[i].IsHighlighted`

Should be:

`mMapDevices[i].Device.NodeTypeCode !== "M" && mMapDevices[i].IsHighlighted`

Answer (score 0):

As seen, James answered the question.

> should it not be mMapDevices[i].Device.NodeTypeCode? What you have is probably undefined, and would explain the behaviour